# Using Spring Security, how to stay on the login page after a successful login?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Using Spring Security, how can I stay on the login page after a successful login?

This part of my Spring config file:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <form-login authentication-failure-url="/index.jsp?failed=true" default-target-url="/index.jsp" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp" />
</http>
```

And I have a jsp fragment file `/WEB-INF/jsp/subhead.jspf`:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

<c:url var="postLoginUrl" value="j_spring_security_check" />
<c:url var="logoutUrl"    value="j_spring_security_logout"/>

<c:if test="${param.failed == true}">Login Failed...</c:if>

<security:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
    <form action="${postLoginUrl}" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="j_username"/>
        Password: <input type="password" name="j_password" />
        <input type="submit" value="Log in"/>
    </form>
</security:authorize>

<security:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
    Hi, <security:authentication property="principal.username"/> <a href="${logoutUrl}">Log out</a>
</security:authorize>
```

I have a page say `test.jsp`:

```
<html>      
  <body>
    <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/subhead.jspf" %>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I make

- login success
- login failed
- logout

all redirect back to the login page (`test.jsp`)?

For now, they will all redirect to `/index.jsp`.

Comment: I'm confused. `index.jsp` is the login page and you want all redirects to point there. You're also claiming all redirects point to `index.jps`. **Does not compute...**

Comment: Actually, I don't want to be directed to `index.jsp` but back to the login page. I want the user to stay on the same page after login.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. The user stays on the same page. You could create a custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` and register it with Spring Security. This handler can simply redirect back to some request parameter.